# Frame size issue in metaphone3 cluster and edit

Tags: csv, frame, openrefine

I am using OpenRefine to clean text from a CSV file. I've been working on the same project for several weeks, and it was working fine until this week.

I am trying to use the 'Cluster and Edit' function from the 'Edit cells' menu. When I use the 'fingerprint' and 'ngram fingerprint' keying function, the frame that opens up inside the browser window is sized appropriately, and I have access to all the buttons and selection menus. However, when I try to use the 'metaphone3' keying function, the frame that opens up is way wider than the browser window, the sliding selection boxes that usually appear in the right side of the frame are not visible, and the buttons across the bottom of the frame ('Select All', 'Unselect All', etc.) are not available. I'd really like to be able to use this keying function option again. Does anyone know what's going on, or how I might be able to fix it.

I am using the OpenRefine 3.3 beta, although a similar issue was happening earlier this week with all keying function options in 3.2 (all were working fine in 3.2 as recently as Friday, 10/25/2019). I am using Firefox, although the same issue happens in Internet Explorer. The system OS is Windows 10 Enterprise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried or errors you have encountered. Also add more tags so the question is visible to a larger audience

Comment: My post describes the problem that I am encountering in the only way I know how to describe it. The problem occurs when I select one particular keying function option from those available in a drop-down menu, so I'm not sure what code I would provide.

Comment: I‘d recommend reporting this on the OpenRefine GitHub site https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/new?template=bug_report.md because it sounds like a bug in the software

Comment: Thanks @OwenStephens -- I'll do that.